# adding values to php multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi in the code below I want to add an extra value for the associative array. For each queryresult in wich elements ["Nietaanwezig"] and ["Aanwezig_diner"] both are 0 I want to add the element ["Nietingevuld"] and set it's value to 1, otherwise i want to add the element ["Nietingevuld"] and set it's value to 0. Albeit I have tried a lot of options, I don't seem to ge a good solution.

```
// numerically indexed array of places
$namen = [];
$queryresult = [];

// TODO: search database for places matching $_GET["geo"]
$search = $_GET["zoekopdracht"];    

if ($search = "diner")
{
    $namen = query ("SELECT * FROM gasten WHERE Typegast = 1");

    foreach ($namen as $naam)
    {
        $queryresult [] = [
            "Voornaam" => $naam["Voornaam"],
            "Achternaam" => $naam["Achternaam"],
            "Nietaanwezig" => $naam["Nietaanwezig"],
            "Aanwezig_diner" => $naam["Aanwezig_Diner"],
        ];        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it all in a single stage then. Build the new child array, modify it as necessary, THEN insert it into the parent array:

```
$temp = array('Voornaam' => $naam['Voornaam'], etc....);
if (whatever you want to check) {
    $temp['something'] = 'else';
}
$queryresult[] = $temp;
```